# Enable HTTP and HTTPS on a custom binding

Tags: c#, http, binding, https, custom-binding

Is it possible to add HTTPS and HTTP support to a custom binding like this?

```
      <customBinding>
    <binding name="RS2010Soap12">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
          messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Ntlm"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Endpoint:

```
  <endpoint address="https://Server1/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RS2010Soap12"
  contract="Program.ReportingService2010Soap"
  name="RS2010Soap12" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to create two bindings and expose two endpoints for your service.